# When do I use Is vs Are

Tags: grammar

4.5 hectares of communal land **are** degrading OR is it 4.5 hectares of communal land **is** degrading?

I sense that it is the first option, but just need to check.

Comment: Welcome to Writing SE! Unfortunately this is more of an English Language question that a Writing one so I'm going to close it. English Language Learners SE is probably a better place to find the info you're looking for. Although before you consider asking there it's worth having a good look through the [existing questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=Is+vs+Are) as they stand a good chance of providing the answer already.